# Cross application cookie access

Tags: web, http, cookies

It was my understanding that cookies are transferred with each subsequent http request, yet if I log in to a web application that uses cookie authentication, say on my browser, other applications on the same machine don't seem to send these previous cookies with *their* requests to the same address. Is my understanding of cookies incorrect?

Comment: When you say "other applications on the same machine" do you mean other non-browser applications on the client? Or other applications on the server? Or something else.

Comment: Yes other non-browser applications although it seems PHP scripts run in the same browser don't have access either. I solved this issue by doing it all within the same app - login, retain cookies, go in to secure area etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies *are* transferred "with each subsequent http request", *on that browser*. Cookie storage is browser-specific.

Unless browsers choose to share their cookie cache somehow, or read those of other applications (which would brand them as malware pretty quickly), they only know of the cookies set *in that browser*

Comment: Interesting, can this be overcome by using a different language? Say PHP? I take it would still retain the browser's context?

Comment: It is completely up to the browser how to handle cookies, this can not be changed, short of creating a software run on their device. If you want to store something persistently for a user, you could make them log in to your page.